# PHP mail function with OS X sendmail

Tags: php, macos, email, sendmail

I'm writing this massive bloc of text today because after migrating to Yosemite the PHP mail function doesn't work anymore on my system and I want to solve this and help people solving this problem once and for all !

I remember that a few monthes ago when I used the PHP mail function, emails where sent automatically from something like **Ellon@MBP-de-Ellon.local**, but after reading a hundred pages for the last two days I haven't found any solution !

Here's the first command that I used to learn what value I should give to the **myhostname variable** in the configuration files following :

```
MBP-de-Ellon:~ Ellon$ echo $HOSTNAME
MBP-de-Ellon.local
```

And here are the contents of my files that needed to be configured (based on tutorials) :

**/etc/hostconfig**

```
# This file is going away

AFPSERVER=-NO-
AUTHSERVER=-NO-
TIMESYNC=-NO-
QTSSERVER=-NO-
MYSQLCOM=-NO-
MAILSERVER=-YES-
```

**/etc/postfix/main.cf**

```
    # INTERNET HOST AND DOMAIN NAMES
# 
# The myhostname parameter specifies the internet hostname of this
# mail system. The default is to use the fully-qualified domain name
# from gethostname(). $myhostname is used as a default value for many
# other configuration parameters.
#
#myhostname = host.domain.tld
#myhostname = virtual.domain.tld
myhostname = MBP-de-Ellon.local

# The mydomain parameter specifies the local internet domain name.
# The default is to use $myhostname minus the first component.
# $mydomain is used as a default value for many other configuration
# parameters.
#
#mydomain = domain.tld

# SENDING MAIL
# 
# The myorigin parameter specifies the domain that locally-posted
# mail appears to come from. The default is to append $myhostname,
# which is fine for small sites.  If you run a domain with multiple
# machines, you should (1) change this to $mydomain and (2) set up
# a domain-wide alias database that aliases each user to
# user@that.users.mailhost.
#
# For the sake of consistency between sender and recipient addresses,
# myorigin also specifies the default domain name that is appended
# to recipient addresses that have no @domain part.
#
#myorigin = $myhostname
#myorigin = $mydomain
```

**/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.10/conf/php.ini**

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
;SMTP = localhost
;smtp_port = 25

; For Win32 only.
;sendmail_from = me@example.com

; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
; PERSONNAL NOTE : i've tried the three settings bellow
;sendmail_path = "env -i /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i"
;sendmail_path = "/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i"
sendmail_path = "sendmail -t -i"
```

**mail.php** (for the test)

```
<?php
    $from = 'MBP-de-Ellon.local';

    if (mail('myemailadress@yahoo.com', 'Subject', 'Message', 'From: ' . $from))
    {
        echo 'Send';
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'Not send';
    }
?>
```

When I load this page in my browser using MAMP it prints "Send" but... nothing go through the mailbox...
When watching with `tail -f /var/log/mail.log` it prints `Operation timed out`.

This is driving me crazy, do you have any idea on how to solve this problem ?
Please forgive my language mistakes.
**Thanks in advance for your answers**.

Answer (score 1):

First, if you're trying to send email from your MacBook using your home internet connection, most residential ISPs block port 25 on outbound connections, which prevents the outgoing mail reaching the destination server (i.e. Gmail's email delivery server).

Second, all mail sent from PHP is queued by and sent from your Mac's Postfix server.  Monitor Postfix' log from Terminal and then run your PHP script.  You'll find specific errors there.

```
$ tail -f /var/log/mail.log
```

Third, you can configure your local Postfix server to authenticate against a SMTP server like Gmail ([Google that one](https://www.google.com/search?q=macos%20postfix%20gmail%20relay)) and send all email using your gmail account (or create a dummy like my-test-acct@gmail.com).  This is always my best option when testing PHP email functions from my laptop at home.  Authentication through a well-known email server also prevents your email from being flagged as spam.